# Registration in Notification Hub with PHP Backend

Tags: php, cordova, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

For user requeriments the backend must be PHP and the app client is in Ionic 2. Based on:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx
https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php
https://github.com/webwarejp/notificationhubs-rest-php

[Create Registration Notification Hub Azure PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35941283/create-registration-notification-hub-azure-php) **Important**

I created this method in php API:

```
    $uri = $this->endpoint . $this->hubPath . "/registrations".NotificationHub::API_VERSION;
    /* print($uri); */
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    $token = $this->generateSasToken($uri);
    $headers = [
        'Authorization: '. $token,
        'Content-Type: '."application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8",
        'x-ms-version: 2015-01',
        'Content-Length: 0'
    ];
    $body = $this->getXmlAndroid($registrationId, $tag);
    print_r($body);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body
     ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
        // Check for errors
    if($response === FALSE){
        print_r(curl_error($ch));
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    print_r($info);
    curl_close($ch);
```

The getXmlAndroid method is simple return xml format with GCM ID

```
private function getXmlAndroid($registrationId){
    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <GcmRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
                        <GcmRegistrationId>'.$registrationId.'</GcmRegistrationId> 
                    </GcmRegistrationDescription>
                </content>
            </entry>';

 }
```

I get the GcmRegistrationId with this function in Ionic 2 app.

```
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';
....
const options: PushOptions = {
  android: { senderID: 'MyIDFirebaseProject'},
  ios: { alert: 'true', badge: true, sound: 'false'},
  windows: {}
};
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
 console.log(registration.registrationId);
});
```

**The problem is always request to Registration method in Notification  API return**

```
[http_code] => 400
```

Where 400 means the "Invalid request body. The registration could not be created because the request was malformed.". I don't understand why this happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why you send Content-Length: 0 header? It may cause a problem.

Comment: Yes this is the stupid problem, this header is unnecessary.